# Why the zoomed image size is same as original one

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, zooming

i'm working on wordpress with woocommerce toolkit.i'm using a plugin YITH WooCommerce Zoom Magnifier - Wordpress plugin to zoom the product image on hover.when i hover the image its showing the original one not zooming at all.

Here is the image dimensions for my woocommerce product images:

```
Catalog Images        150×150 px (Hard Crop ticked)
Single Product Image  270×270 px (Hard Crop ticked)
Product Thumbnails     90×90 px (Hard Crop ticked)
```

when i set the product image as size of 270x270 the zoomed image size is same as original one.it doesn't zoom at all.

when i put the product image of bigger size 1000x1000 it gt croped badly though zoom worked in this case.how can i make the image to be good in quality.
Here is a link to my page: (when product image size is big):http://karam.in/domestic/product/pn-01/

(when product image size is small): http://karam.in/domestic/product/pn-02/